# filter option in list view fragment activity

Tags: android, listview, search, fragment, addtextchangedlistener

hi friend i want to add search option to list view in fragment activity but i cannot access list view adapter from addTextChangedListener. can you please help me.i cannot find answer from internet,can you please help me to fix this.data loading part working properly.i want to filtered data by code.

[image]

```
   public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment implements  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
        private static final String TAG_ID = "GUID";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "GUNO";
        private static final String TAG_Code = "ShipNo";
        private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Description";
        private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
        private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

        private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";
       // private static final int RESULT_OK = 1 ;
       // private static final int RESULT_CANCELED = 2 ;

        private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

        ImageView imgPreview;
        private VideoView videoPreview;

        private String baid = "";
        private PopupWindow pwindo;
        Button btndeliver;
        Button btnreject;
        Button btncannot;
        Button btnother;
        Button btnClosePopup;
        EditText inputSearch;

      //  Button btnCallPopup;
      //  Button  btnwtsappPopup;
        public String pnumb;
        public String CusMobileNo;


        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray contacts = null;

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;


        public FindPeopleFragment(){}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            Movie movie = new Movie();
            baid=movie.getGUID();

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

            contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



            WebServiceCaller webServiceCaller = new WebServiceCaller();
            String Result = webServiceCaller.mydespatchDettails(baid);

            try {
                JSONObject Jasonobject = new JSONObject(Result);
                JSONArray Jarray = Jasonobject.getJSONArray("PendingDespatch");

                for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = json_data.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = json_data.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String code = json_data.getString(TAG_Code);
                    String address = json_data.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);

                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_Code, code);
                    contact.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);

                }
                ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

                  final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity()
                        ,contactList,
                        (R.layout.list_item), new String[] { TAG_NAME,TAG_Code,TAG_ID
                        ,TAG_ADDRESS }, new int[] { R.id.code,
                        R.id.names, R.id.city,R.id.address });

                list.setAdapter(adapter);

                list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                //list.setListAdapter(adapter);
                inputSearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

                inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int count, int after) {

                      System.out.println("Text ["+cs+"]");
                     FindPeopleFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 

    //***This is problem i cannot access adapter here..i want to to search by code***  





                        // FindPeopleFragment.TAG_Code..getFilter().filter(cs);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return rootView;
        }
```

Comment: `final ListAdapter adapter` -> `final SimpleAdapter adapter` when you do it `adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);` should work just fine

Comment: Thnaks bro i woks..thanks lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing this line:

```
FindPeopleFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
```

into:

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
```

or

How about using AutoCompleteTextview for your search feature.

[AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) documentation

[Example](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#AutoComplete)

Comment: dear friend in here adapter shows as underline red.. if  i make adapter final ,getFilter() shows as red .i cannot understand what is the problem..great help bro..i 'am stack here from two days

Comment: @KasunChaturanga if it works, can you accept my answer? Glad to be of help.